# POST doesnt works when using Placeholders and Masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, master-pages, placeholder

I tried to write a logging page to my "project". I found some solution based on session state. It's a very simple project and works fine but when I implemented that thing in my code it doesn't works. It doesn't see the values form POST method, they are empty. The only difference in my project is that I used MasterPage and Placeholders... Could this somehow affect the flow of data?

Found project - controls

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFE0C0" Height="50px" Width="192px">
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="login"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TBlogin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="hasło"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TBhaslo" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Zaloguj się!" Width="190px" PostBackUrl="loguj.aspx" />
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SDSUzytkownik" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringSklep %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [uzytkownik] WHERE (([login] = @Log) AND ([haslo] = @Has))">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" FormField="TBlogin" Name="Log" />
            <asp:FormParameter DefaultValue="&quot;&quot;" FormField="TBhaslo" Name="Has" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    &nbsp;

    <asp:Label ID="LComment" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label><br />
    <br />
    <asp:FormView ID="FVUzytkownik" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="userID"
        DataSourceID="SDSUzytkownik" ForeColor="#333333" OnDataBound="FVUzytkownik_DataBound">

        <ItemTemplate>
            Hello
            <asp:Label ID="imieNazwiskoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("imieNazwisko") %>'></asp:Label>!<br />
            <br />
            Your login:
            <asp:Label ID="loginLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("login") %>'></asp:Label><br />

            Your email:
            <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label><br />
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:FormView>
    <asp:Label ID="LabelTEST" runat="server" Text="LabelTestujący"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

code behind

```cs
protected void FVUzytkownik_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelTEST.Text = "Im in";
    if (FVUzytkownik.Row != null)
    {
        Session["Logged"] = Request.Form["TBlogin"];
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        LZalogowanyJako.Text = "You are logged as:" + Session["Logged"];

        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/>Im logged <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
    else if (Request.Form["TBlogin"] != null && Session["Logged"] == null)
    {
        LComment.Text = "Logging failed. Wrong pass.";
        LComment.Visible = true;
        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/>Loggin failed <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
    else {
        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/> All failed <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
}
```

My code - placeholder on Masterpage

```html
<div class="content">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="/acc/Log.aspx" method="post">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="middle" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</div>
```

Place Holder Content

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="middle" runat="server">
    <h2>Logowanie</h2>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Login:</td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="loginInput" runat="server" placeholder="ImieNazwisko" Width="155px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pass:</td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="hasloInput" runat="server" placeholder="8 znaków" Width="155px" TextMode="password"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="zaloguj" runat="server" Height="40px" ImageUrl="~/images/zaloguj.png" PostBackUrl="/logowanie/Logowanie.aspx" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [uzytkownicy] WHERE (([login] = @login) AND ([haslo] = @haslo))">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:FormParameter FormField="loginInput" Name="login" Type="String" />
                            <asp:FormParameter FormField="hasloInput" Name="haslo" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:FormView ID="FVUzytkownik" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="userID"
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" OnDataBound="FVUzytkownik_DataBound" EnableModelValidation="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            Hello!
                         <br />
                            Your login:
                                 <asp:Label ID="loginLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("login") %>'></asp:Label><br />

                            <br />
                            Your email :
                       <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:FormView>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelZalogowanyJako" runat="server" Text="message log "></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelTEST" runat="server" Text="LabelTESTowanie"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

and the same behind code

```cs
protected void FVUzytkownik_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabelTEST.Text = "Im in";
    if (FVUzytkownik.Row != null)
    {
        Session["Logged"] = Request.Form["TBlogin"];
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        LZalogowanyJako.Text = "You are logged as:" + Session["Logged"];

        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/>Im logged <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
    else if (Request.Form["TBlogin"] != null && Session["Logged"] == null)
    {
        LComment.Text = "Logging failed. Wrong pass.";
        LComment.Visible = true;
        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/>Loggin failed <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
    else {
        LabelTEST.Text = "<br/> All failed <br/><br/> databse ROW =  " + FVUzytkownik.Row + "<br/><br/> Session =  " + Session["Logged"] + " <br/><br/> Request Form Login = " + Request.Form["TBlogin"];
    }
}
```

and the screen of effect:

[image: s]

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear, though from the code you posted I see you're attempting to use multiple `form` tags. Well, while it is possible, ASP.NET WebForms wasn't designed that way. If you insist to use multiple forms then only one of them MUST have the `runat="server"` attribute. 
But you better switch to other approach, such as `asp:UpdatePanel` if you need such functionality.

Comment: I used 'form' once, on the Master Page and the Placeholder inside it. The second way is to delete it from Master Page and put into Placeholder but nothing changed about the functionality, it still doesn't works.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the HTML rendered. It contains two forms since you've used the tag on both master page and in the place holder - not a good practice in WebForms. And DO NOT remove the form tag from the master page; it is required for ASP.NET WebForms to work properly.

Comment: Hmm. Okay so I deleted the `form` from place holder... You suggested to use `asp:UpdatePanel` but which parts should be inside ? What about the "behind code" part it still waiting for the values from POST. In fact, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Use of `UpdatePanel`s leverages so called "partial page updates". By implementing it you could send any piece of data to the server, regardles it is on a form or not. It represents an approach, not just coding element, so you should familiarize yourself before starting its implementation. In the code behind, use the controls declared on the page instead looking in request's fields for posted values...